# Feeding tf.data Dataset with multidimensional output to Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, semantic-segmentation

I want to feed a **tf.data** Dataset to a Keras model, but I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DatasetV1Adapter' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

**This dataset will be used to solve a segmentation problem, so both input and output will be images (3D tensors)**

The dataset is created with this code:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(TRAIN_PATH + "*.png",shuffle=False)

def process_path(file_path):
  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = tf.image.decode_png(img, channels=3)
  train_image_path=tf.strings.regex_replace(file_path,"image","mask")
  mask = tf.io.read_file(train_image_path)
  mask = tf.image.decode_png(mask, channels=1)
  mask = tf.squeeze(mask)
  mask = tf.one_hot(tf.cast(mask, tf.int32), Num_Classes, axis = -1)
  return img,mask

dataset = dataset.map(process_path)
dataset = dataset.batch(32,drop_remainder=True)
```

Taking an item from the dataset shows that I get a tuple containing an input tensor and an output tensor, whose dimensions are correct:

Input:  (batch-size, image height, image width, 3 channels)

Output: (batch-size, image height, image width, 4 channels)

When fitting the model I get an error:

```
model.fit(dataset, epochs = 50)
```

Comment: Which tensorflow version are you using? There is no ```tf.image.decode_png``` attribute in TF2.2. Try using ```tf.io.decode_png``` or ```tf.io.decode_image```

Comment: When you pass a dataset to [`fit`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit), Keras expects it to return tuples of batches, either `(inputs, targets)` or `(inputs, targets, sample_weights)`. Your dataset returns dicts of batches.

Comment: @jdehesa, even replacing the dictionary with a tuple leads to the same error. I've replaced "return {"input":img,"output":mask}", with return img, mask, with no success.

Comment: @DwijMehta, tf.image.decode_png seems to work fine: I get the image. TF version is 2.0.0

Comment: @jdehesa: I edited the question putting the version without the dictionary output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the provem moving to Keras 2.4.3 and Tensorflow 2.2

Everything was right but apparently the previous release of Keras did not manage this tf.data correctly.

[Here](https://yann-leguilly.gitlab.io/post/2019-12-14-tensorflow-tfdata-segmentation/)'s a tutorial I've found very useful on this.